# Is there any order for Java main thread and user created thread execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

```
public class SimpleThreads {
    // Display a message, preceded by the name of the current thread
    static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n", threadName, message);
    }

    private static class MessageLoop implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            String importantInfo[] = { "Mares eat oats", "Does eat oats","Little lambs eat ivy", "A kid will eat ivy too" };
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
                    threadMessage(importantInfo[i]);
                }
            } catch (Exception  e) {
                threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        threadMessage("Starting MessageLoop thread");
        Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
        t.start();
        threadMessage("Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
main: Starting MessageLoop thread
main: Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish
Thread-0: Mares eat oats
Thread-0: Does eat oats
Thread-0: Little lambs eat ivy
Thread-0: A kid will eat ivy too
```

Here at first the main thread printed the message 'main: Starting MessageLoop thread'. After that I started Thread-0 OR MessageLoop thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
t.start();
```

But before starting/printing Thread-0 messages its printing 'main' thread message 'main: Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish' and Thread-0 was executed after that only. Why ?

Comment: How is `Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop()); t.start();` (which is started in `main`) supposed to start before `main`? What part is surprising here?

Comment: `main` will anyway invoked first

Comment: Because starting a thread is not instantaneous, there is overhead to start a thread. Main thread simply gets to second `threadMessage()` call *faster* than thread gets thru its startup overhead and gets to its `threadMessage()` call. It's a simple question of speed. It's a race condition, but the main thread usually wins the race, because it has nothing else to do between `start()` and `threadMessage()`.

Comment: Without explicit synchronization, there is no guarantee in which order those statements (in different threads) will be printed. This means that it is even not sure that the `waiting` message from `main` thread will always be printed first. The only guarantee you have with this code is that all messages from `main` thread are printed in order, and that all messages from `Thread-0` are printed in order.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replies.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is normal and must be expected, although you can't count on it either way.

You seem to expect the `main` thread to **wait** for the second thread to be running. This, however, is not the case with your code. **The point of starting a second thread is concurrent execution**, implying that that you can't count on the sequence of execution just because the statements in code are sequential.

If you want the main thread to `wait` for the other thread to execute, then you need to synchronize them. ***This, however, defeats the purpose of starting the second thread in your case.*** If you wanted main thread to wait for second thread, you could then just call the method without starting the second thread.

Googling "java concurrency" led to, among other pages, [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). That doc explains a lot of these concepts.

Answer (score -1):

Because invoking `start()` on a thread doesn't make the thread effectively executed right now.
It is the way which works multithreading.

From `Thread.start()` documentation :

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread.
>
> **The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current
>   thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other
>   thread (which executes its run method).**

The `main` thread is currently executed as you invoke  `t.start();` .
The thread will at a time be paused by the JVM but you don't master when.

In your specific case, you will get a reproducible behavior.
As after `t.start();`, you have a statement very fast to execute  :

```
 threadMessage("Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish");
```

it never doesn't let the main thread to be paused and the new thread to be effectively run.

Add  after `t.start();`, some statements that take more time to be executed in the main thread or invoke `sleep()` on it and you should see a different behavior.

Comment: How does that explain why the main thread always prints first? I.e. `Waiting` is printed before first thread message is printed.